# wpf DependencyProperty Not accepting default value for Image Imagesourc

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a dependency property for image path
It shows Argument exception **default value type does not match type of property**

```
[Description("Set image path for button "), Category("Common Properties")]
public ImageSource ImagePath
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImagePathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImagePathProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImagePath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePathProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImagePath", typeof(ImageSource),
    typeof(TaskButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));
```

Can anyone please suggest what to write in  argument of this object new UIPropertyMetadata(_argument)

Comment: Compiles fine at my end.

Comment: okay okay u are right i was just build issue,

Comment: On a sidenote you can omit setting `PropertyMetadata`. It will be default value anyhow.

Comment: thanks rohit for your response..

Comment: Please delete the question if you are not looking for any answers.